# OWL: entity composed by set of other entities

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-web, protege

I am trying to model a class representing a particular game in OWL. Let us call this game *GameX*. A game of *GameX* is composed of several matches. I would like to model the relationship between *GameX* and its matches in OWL. I am using Protégé as editor.

My attempt is the following: I have created a class `GameX`, a class `Match` and an object property `composedOf`. Then, in the description of `GameX`, I have stated that `GameX` is a subclass of the expression `composedOf only Match`.

Is this approach expressing the situation I have described in the first paragraph?

The only related question I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264795/how-to-define-composition-properties-on-protege), but I don't think it clearly addresses my doubt.

Comment: I would more go for `GameX SubClassOf: (composedOf some Match) and (composedOf only Match)` which states that `GameX` is composed of at least one match and all the `GameX` is composed of are `Match`es. Note, the `only` expression is only used for inference, i.e. any thing that is related to a `GameX` instance will be a `Match` (by inference) - this is **not** a constraint.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. Please, feel free to post this as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925692/owl-entity-composed-by-set-of-other-entities#comment118330922_66925692) for the answer.

TL;DR: use `GameX SubClassOf: (composedOf some Match) and (composedOf only Match)`.